# Filter then query

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have an index with thousands of documents (say 10000). 
The query I run against it is for autocomplete search: `filtered` with `filter` matching small subset of docs (say 100) and `query` being `match_phrase_prefix`.

The problem is that I get the results I expect only if I set large `max_expansions` (say 1000, by default it's 50 right?).
If I get it right, ES first does a query, finds `max_expansions` of terms, and then applies filter to what it found so far.
If the `max_expansion` is small, chances are high that documents matching filter won't be included at all.

The question is if there's a way to do filtering first to reduce the result set?

Completion suggester won't work as it doesn't allow filtering.
Prefix filter won't work as it doesn't analyze query strings and I need that.

*ES 1.0.1*.

Upd. Here are the queries to reproduce:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/test_max_expansions/'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test_max_expansions/'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test_max_expansions/posts/_mapping' -d '
{
    "posts" : {
        "properties" : {
            "title" : {"type" : "string"},
            "hidden" : {"type" : "boolean"}
        }
    }
}'

for i in {1..1000}; do curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_max_expansions/posts/$i" -d "{\"title\" : \"a$i\", \"hidden\" : false}"; done

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test_max_expansions/posts/1001' -d '
{
    "title" : "a1001",
    "hidden" : true
}'


curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test_max_expansions/posts/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": { "term": { "hidden": true } },
            "query": {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                    "title": {
                        "query": "a"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

It returns 0 hits whereas if I add `max_expansions: 1000` it returns the document I want

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the Filtered Query:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html

The behaviour you describe sounds more like the post filter:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-request-post-filter.html

UPDATE
Since the other queries are clearly not your solution, I had some succes with this query.

```
GET /test_max_expansions/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "title": {
              "query": "a1",
              "max_expansions": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "hidden": {
              "value": false
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I mentioned I use Filtered Query at the moment. Post filter does opposite to what I want. I'd rather need "pre filter".

Comment: Hmm, than I do not understand it, the filtered query should filter before scoring, that is on of the advantages. I guess I misunderstand the problem. Sorry.

Comment: @max_i filtered query does what you need, filters are executed before the queries (and properly cached when it makes sense). The query is executed against the documents that are left after applying the filters.

Comment: @javanna please see the updated question - I've added gist. It returns  0 hits whereas if I add max_expansions: 1000 it returns the document I want.

Comment: Hi @max_i Interesting question, based on your code snippet I conducted some experiments of my own. Even with just 4 records you can find the problem you exposed. Reading the documentation again, it does say: "A query that applies a filter to the results of another query." The difference with for instance the post filter is that the filtered query does filter the results before facets are calculated. I guess you can use the bool query with a must_not, maybe that is what you need.

Comment: @JettroCoenradie thx for suggestion, I just tried it but the result is the same - the document is only found if max_expansions is high

Comment: I included a bool query that seems to work for me, can you try if this is what you want?

Comment: @JettroCoenradie nope it didn't work either. maybe it depends on the number of documents in the index.

Comment: @javanna I found a way to do what I want, though I'm a bit confused with your comment regarding `filtered` query: _"filters are executed before the queries"_. Why does ES documentation say _"A query that applies a filter to the results of another query"_ about it then?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this, the only way I found to filter small subset of documents and then run match_phrase_prefix on them:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test_max_expansions/posts/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "query": {
                    "match_phrase_prefix": {
                        "title": {
                            "query": "a"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "query": {
                "term": { "hidden": true }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```